# Picklist Default Values Inconsistency across New Case

Tags: apex, picklist, service

We're encountering a perplexing issue in our Production Environment regarding a Picklist named "Workflow Step." Specifically, within a Record Type titled "System Issue," the default value for Workflow Step is set to "Assessing."

Here's the crux of the problem: When navigating to a Case and selecting "New" to create a record under the System Issue Record Type, the edit page correctly displays Workflow Step defaulted to "Assessing."

However, we have a self-lookup field on Case labeled "Parent System Issue." In a scenario where we're creating a new Parent System Issue from an existing Case, the Workflow Step field fails to default to "Assessing" when selecting "New Case" and then opting for the System Issue Record Type.

This inconsistency is puzzling, especially since it occurs for the same user in different contexts. We're currently at a loss as to where to begin troubleshooting. Any guidance on what aspects to investigate would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And the major issue is all the lower environments are not having that issue.

Comment: Workflow Step (Picklist) and Parent System Issue (Lookup) both of these fields are in Case object? and when you are trying to create a New Case from the Case object's tab list view, it is populating the Workflow Step to "Assessing", but during this same event, when you are trying to create a new Case in the Parent System Issue and select System issue record type, this new pop up window is not defaulting "Assessing" for this new case record with System Issue record type?

Comment: Yes @prem22 Both the fields 
- Parent System Issue (Self Lookup)
- Workflow Step (Picklist) 
are on case. 
And the New Case Popup window is not defaulting to Assessing for the Workflow Step Picklist. This is also happening only on the Production Environment not on any other lower environments.